# Hide Text Box When Radio Is Selected

Tags: jquery, text, hide

I have a data entry form on my site which contains multiple checkboxes, two radio buttons and a text field. I want to make the text field un-editable if one of my radio buttons is selected. With an error message if the customer tries to type in it. I'm new to Jquery and web coding so am having trouble finding relevant answers.

The radio buttons and text area are as follows

```
    <form method="post" class="required-form" action="php/addcompanyengine.php">
  <ul class="forms">


    <p class="Region">Please select the type of listing you desire</p>
    <ol>
        <li><label class="checkbox">Bronze Listing</label>
        <input type="radio" name="listing[]" id="listing" value="Bronze" checked></li>
        </ol>
        <ol>
        <li><label class="checkbox">Silver Listing</label>
        <input type="radio" name="listing[]" id="listing" value="Silver"></li>
    </ol>



      <label for="Description">Description:<br /><br />
            (Silver listings only <br /> <br />
            Maximum 400 characters)</label>
            <textarea name="Description" cols="20" id="Description" maxlength="400" ></textarea>
```

Basically if the customer leaves the radio button on Bronze (the default) I want the text field unavailable, if they select silver I'd like it available for them to type into.

Many thanks, it's much appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't have two elements in your page with the same id. You should use a class if your using it for CSS style.

Comment: You could disable your textfield by defaul and enable it on radio change ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you already have jQuery loaded (**note the class attribute instead of ID**):

```
<ol>
    <li><label class="checkbox">Bronze Listing</label>
    <input type="radio" name="listing[]" class="listing" value="Bronze" checked></li>
    </ol>
    <ol>
    <li><label class="checkbox">Silver Listing</label>
    <input type="radio" name="listing[]" class="listing" value="Silver"></li>
</ol>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.listing').change({
            if ($(this).val() == 'Bronze') {
                $('#Description').attr('readonly','readonly');
            } else {
                $('#Description').removeAttr('readonly');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/AZ7wJ/

If you want the textarea originally non-editable as well, you can add the `readonly="readonly"` attribute to it.

Answer (score 0):

Before starting:

- Change the radio `input` IDs so they are different.
- Add the `readonly` attribute to your `textarea`.

Let's assume you are using `listingBronze` as the Bronze radio `input id`.

```
//we listen to the change event
$("#listingBronze").change(function(event){
    //we tell readonly is equal to bronze checked status
    $('#Description').prop('readonly',(!!$(this).prop("checked")));
});
```

This simple.
As `readonly = checked` the code gets really small.

NOTE: using !! assures the value will be boolean as it's a not not value.

Optionally you could `hide` and `show` the textarea, discarding the `readonly` attribute in the process:

```
$("#listingBronze").change(function(event){
    $('#Description').show();
    if(!!$(this).prop("checked")) $('#Description').hide();
});
```

We show the textarea on every change, then check the `checked` attribute and hide if true.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the accepted answer should be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.listing').change(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == 'Bronze') {
                $('#Description').attr('readonly','readonly');
            } else {
                $('#Description').removeAttr('readonly');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Note the function() after change